# Monogame XAML Reset CoreWindow?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, monogame

Heey,

I got a problem. I'm running through all the last tests I had to do for finishing my game but now I bumped into a problem. Whenever I initialize the game while holding my game in portrait the game swaps to landscape but the `Window.Current.CoreWindow` won't update. So the Xaml template creates a window based on the portrait settings instead of the landscape settings. How can I change the CoreWindow or update it before my entire game gets initialized?

After some research I tried reproducing it with the game [ARMED!](http://www.armedgame.com/) which I know uses the Xaml template and even there I found this problem that when I opened it in portrait the window wouldn't update when moving back to landscape so being stuck with an broken interface/game.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CoreWindow won't refresh on his own. It'll only refresh inside you Update(). So if you want to handle changes to the CoreWindow before you hit the Initializing part you need to handle them yourself.

```
_coreWindow = Window.Current.CoreWindow;

// Create the game.
_game = XamlGame<Main>.Create("", _coreWindow, this);

_coreWindow.Activate();
_coreWindow.Dispatcher.ProcessEvents(CoreProcessEventsOption.ProcessAllIfPresent);
```

Here you see that I create my game by the current CoreWindow. After the constructor of my game is done I manually check and process any changes of the CoreWindow which may have happen in the mean time (mainly orientation changes) and process them so that when my game Initializes it'll run in the proper full landscape resolution.

It may not be the most clean solution but it does the job in my case.